# Excel column distribution behavior during loop process, is it possible?

Tags: java, apache-poi, export-to-excel

Using ***Apache POI 3.9***, I want to map some values to an Excel template that looks similar to this:

[image: Excel template with data]

Looks pretty easy, at least for the ***Seller*** table in which I can map the values from my bean  without problems.

However, the issue I am facing is related to the ***Products*** table because I need to set the data from my bean for each column which makes the logic a little bit complex since during the loop process I'll need to look for the next column letter:

***e.g.*** My first product data will be set under *B7* then at *C7, D7, E7, etc* until the loop ends.

*(Just to know, for this example template I am just showing the "Name" attribute of the product but each one has around 35 attributes in real life, that's why I am not showing the data in rows since the table won't look so friendly to the user in horizontal view).*

***So, my question is:***

> What happen If my products count is more than the total letters of the 
>   alphabet, how can I get the right column and cell during the loop process 
>   to set my product bean data following Excel column distribution?

With *"Excel column distribution"* I mean the following:

***e.g.*** In Excel, when going to the column which contains the last letter of the alphabet *"Z"* then the columns continue showing *AA, AB, AC, etc*.

[image: Example of Excel columns distribution]

### Is it possible?

This is what I've tried *(using dummy data)* and this will work until getting into the letter *"Z"* column:

**Empty Excel template used in this code snippet can be downloaded at:** https://www.dropbox.com/s/eo0s54o9vkqhlbl/template.xls

```
package com.app.test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.IndexedColors;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;


/**
 * Test class for generating Excel sheet
 */
public class ExportTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        CellReference ref;

        // Load template
        InputStream fis = ExportTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/template.xls");
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
        fis.close();

        // Constants
        final String TBL_FIRSTCOLUMN = "B"; // Starting product table column at sheet (in which the first product data will be set)
        final int MAX_PRODUCTS = 25; // Max. products added to the dummy products list (this will set the last product to the "Z" column)
        final int TBL_STARTROW = 7; // Starting product table row number at sheet (in which the first product data will be set)
        final int TBL_ATTR_ROWS = 1; // Number of attribute rows at products table (in this case just "Name")

        // Generate dummy data with seller information
        LinkedHashMap<String, String> cellMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
        cellMap.put("B2", "1");
        cellMap.put("B3", "Company");
        cellMap.put("B4", "US");

        // Generate dummy data with product information
        List<String> products = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0; i < MAX_PRODUCTS; ++i) {
            products.add("Chocolate");
        }

        // Declare style for cells
        CellStyle style = workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setLeftBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
        style.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setRightBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
        style.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setTopBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
        style.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_THIN);
        style.setBottomBorderColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());

        // Get template sheet
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        // Set values to "Seller" table
        for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : cellMap.entrySet()) {
            ref = new CellReference(entry.getKey());
            sheet.getRow(ref.getRow()).getCell(ref.getCol()).setCellValue(entry.getValue());
        }

        // Set values to "Products" table
        for(int i = 0; i < products.size(); ++i) {

            // Get product name
            String name = products.get(i);
            String num = String.valueOf(i + 1);

            // Get char representation of the letter, this will allow me to get
            // C, D, E...Z columns but then I will get a IllegalArgumentException
            // if my products count exceed the alphabet letters. At this point I'll 
            // need to follow Excel column distribution behavior.
            String nextLetter = String.valueOf((char)(TBL_FIRSTCOLUMN.charAt(0) + i));

            for(int j = 0; j < TBL_ATTR_ROWS; ++j) {
                // Get cell reference of B7 then C7, etc
                ref = new CellReference(nextLetter + (TBL_STARTROW + j));

                // Check if row/cell exists, otherwise it will throw NullPointerException when trying to get each one
                Row row = sheet.getRow(ref.getRow());
                if(row == null) {
                    row = sheet.createRow(ref.getRow());
                }
                Cell cell = row.getCell(ref.getCol());
                if(cell == null) {
                    cell = row.createCell(ref.getCol());
                }

                // Set value and style to cell
                cell.setCellValue(name + num);
                cell.setCellStyle(style);
            }
        }

        // Write workbook to file
        String path = String.format("%s%s%s", System.getProperty("user.home"), System.getProperty("file.separator"), "exported.xls");
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Then, If the products count exceeds the alphabet letters I will get the following exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid
>   column index (-11).  Allowable column range for BIFF8 is (0..255) or
>   ('A'..'IV')   at
>   org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.checkBounds(HSSFCell.java:939)
>     at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell.(HSSFCell.java:153)
>     at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow.createCell(HSSFRow.java:148)
>     at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow.createCell(HSSFRow.java:126)
>     at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow.createCell(HSSFRow.java:39)
>     at
>   com.app.test.ExportTest.main(ExportTest.java:99)

*(To replicate this try using `MAX_PRODUCTS = 26`, **NOT** 27 - alphabet count - since we are starting at B column on Excel sheet).*

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call a utility method in Apache POI -- [`CellReference.convertNumToColString`](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/util/CellReference.html#convertNumToColString%28int%29) to map your column number into an Excel column designation.

> Takes in a 0-based base-10 column and returns a ALPHA-26 representation. eg column #3 -> D

Since you're starting with column "B" (`1`), add `1` to `i` first.

```
String nextLetter = String.valueOf(CellReference.convertNumToColString(i + 1));
```